Internal Category Theory for Double Fibrations
Are there books (besides Handbook of Categorical Algebra Vol 1) that introduce the theory of internal category theory? My purpose for this is to have an intuition for double fibrations, at least for how they are defined in the literature.
I find the Handbook of categorical algebra to be very dry.

Some references are listed on the nLab. For internal higher category theory (internal to an $\infty$-topos), you can look at some articles by Louis Martini and Sebastian Wolf on this topic.
